# Search Annotations in mapView

Tags: ios, uitableview, search, annotations, mkmapview

In my project i have a `mapView` with a lot of `annotations` & i would like to add a search functionality to the map so i can search those `annotations` and quickly find the annotation i want.

I followed a tutorial i found on the web but it searches globally (`MKLocalSearch`) and not the annotations.

I tried looking for a tutorial \ Help for my problem but i couldn't get any help for a long time now.

**I've made these annotations :**

```
let LitzmanLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(32.100668,34.775192)
        // Drop a pin
        let Litzman = MKPointAnnotation()
        Litzman.coordinate = LitzmanLocation
        Litzman.title = "Litzman Bar"
        Litzman.subtitle = "נמל תל אביב 18,תל אביב"
        mapView.addAnnotation(Litzman)

        let ShalvataLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(32.101145,34.775163)
        // Drop a pin
        let Shalvata = MKPointAnnotation()
        Shalvata.coordinate = ShalvataLocation
        Shalvata.title = "Shalvata"
        Shalvata.subtitle = "האנגר 28,נמל תל אביב"
        mapView.addAnnotation(Shalvata)


        let MarkidLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(32.074961,34.781679)
        // Drop a pin
        let Markid = MKPointAnnotation()
        Markid.coordinate = MarkidLocation
        Markid.title = "Markid"
        Markid.subtitle = "אבן גבירול 30,תל אביב"
        mapView.addAnnotation(Markid)
```

## Currently the search i have:

**MapViewController:**

```
    //All my Map code is here
    }
    }
    }
    extension MapViewController: HandleMapSearch {
    func dropPinZoomIn(placemark:MKPlacemark){
        // cache the pin
        selectedPin = placemark
        // clear existing pins
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = placemark.coordinate
        annotation.title = placemark.name
        if let _ = placemark.locality,
            let _ = placemark.administrativeArea {
            annotation.subtitle = ""
        }
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(placemark.coordinate, span)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }  
}
```

**SearchTable:**

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class LocationSearchTable : UITableViewController {

    var matchingItems = [CustomAnnotations]()
    var mapView: MKMapView? = nil

    var handleMapSearchDelegate:HandleMapSearch? = nil

    func parseAddress(selectedItem:MKPlacemark) -> String {
        // put a space between "4" and "Melrose Place"
        let firstSpace = (selectedItem.subThoroughfare != nil && selectedItem.thoroughfare != nil) ? " " : ""
        // put a comma between street and city/state
        let comma = (selectedItem.subThoroughfare != nil || selectedItem.thoroughfare != nil) && (selectedItem.subAdministrativeArea != nil || selectedItem.administrativeArea != nil) ? ", " : ""
        // put a space between "Washington" and "DC"
        let secondSpace = (selectedItem.subAdministrativeArea != nil && selectedItem.administrativeArea != nil) ? " " : ""
        let addressLine = String(
            format:"%@%@%@%@%@%@%@",
            // street number
            selectedItem.subThoroughfare ?? "",
            firstSpace,
            // street name
            selectedItem.thoroughfare ?? "",
            comma,
            // city
            selectedItem.locality ?? "",
            secondSpace,
            // state
            selectedItem.administrativeArea ?? ""
        )
        return addressLine
    }

    func search(keywords:String) {
        self.matchingItems.removeAll()
        for annotation in self.mapView!.annotations {
            if annotation.isKindOfClass(CustomAnnotations) {
                //Just an example here for searching annotation by title, you could add other filtering actions else.
                if (annotation.title??.rangeOfString(keywords) != nil) {
                    self.matchingItems.append(annotation as! CustomAnnotations)
                }
            }
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

}

extension LocationSearchTable : UISearchResultsUpdating {
    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        guard let mapView = mapView,
            let searchBarText = searchController.searchBar.text else { return }
        let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
        request.naturalLanguageQuery = searchBarText
        request.region = mapView.region
        let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
        search.startWithCompletionHandler { response, _ in
            guard let response = response else {
                return
            }
            self.matchingItems = response.mapItems
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

}

extension LocationSearchTable {
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return matchingItems.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MapSearchCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        let selectedItem = matchingItems[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = selectedItem.title
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = selectedItem.subtitle
        return cell
    }

}


extension LocationSearchTable {
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let selectedItem = matchingItems[indexPath.row]//.placemark
        handleMapSearchDelegate?.dropPinZoomIn(selectedItem)
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

My question is how i can turn this to only search my annotations and not search all over the world with MKLocalSearch.

I'm a beginner coder using 2.3 and Xcode 8

Thanks you for helping.

## Errors From Answer :

[image]

Comment: The errors are caused by incompatibilities between Swift 2.3 and Swift 3. Please try convert the answer's syntax to Swift 2.3, or upgrade your xcode to the latest version with Swift 3. Sorry, I cannot provide the Swift 2.3 version codes, because I don't have the old xcode.

Comment: I prefer to upgrade your xcode, it's better to keep yourself up to date, ;)

Comment: Yea haha you are right. but I'm a huge noob and for me swift 3  looks like a huge change and I'm afraid i wont be able to fix all the errors and stuff ... thats why I'm not diving into it

Comment: @YunCHEN i managed to translate to swift 2.3 ... but now i have these errors which are not the same can you help me please ? :\

Answer (score 0):

(**Swift 3**, just take main idea for reference if it's not convenient to convert Swift version)

**First**, define a custom class inherited from MKPointAnnotation for distinguishing your annotations from others:

```
class CustomedAnnottion: MKPointAnnotation{
    //You can also add some varible for saving custom data, like: var id:Int?
}
```

**Second**, add the annotations with your custom annotation class:

```
let ShalvataLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(32.101145,34.775163)
let Shalvata = CustomedAnnottion()
Shalvata.coordinate = ShalvataLocation
Shalvata.title = "Shalvata"
Shalvata.subtitle = "האנגר 28,נמל תל אביב"
mapView.addAnnotation(Shalvata)
```

**Third**, change your search table view datasource to:

```
var matchingItems = [CustomedAnnottion]()
```

**Fourth(The most important for searching your custom annotations)**, implement a search function like this:

```
func search(keywords:String) {
    self.matchingItems.removeAll()
    for annotation in self.mapView.annotations {
        if annotation.isKind(of: CustomedAnnottion.classForCoder()) {
            //Just an example here for searching annotation by title, you could add other filtering actions else.
            if (annotation.title??.range(of: keywords) != nil) {
                self.matchingItems.append(annotation as! CustomedAnnottion)
            }
        }
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

**Finally**, change the tableView's 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' method to:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MapSearchCell", for: indexPath)
    let selectedItem = matchingItems[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = selectedItem.title
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = selectedItem.subtitle
    return cell
}
```

These are general steps for implementing your requirements, feel free to change any code to meet your specific needs.

Comment: Hey i got these last 2 errors remaining then i can run and build and try out the search...Can you help me fix the errors?

Comment: @NewbieQuestions, you are still searching MKMapItem objects, the question is what the relation between MKMapItems and your Annotations is?  MKMapItem.name == Annotation.title?

Comment: i have no idea to be honest ... I will update to my current code so u will be able to see more clearly....i guess what i want to type to search is the subtitle or the title to search the annotations.....

Comment: can we delete everything related to MKLocalSearch cause i dont want anything to do with global searching?

Comment: @NewbieQuestions, Yes, if you only want search your custom annotations.